# Vue.js new script setup with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Thanks for reading my question.

I'm trying to get the new `<script setup>` syntax (Composition API) with Vue.js 3.2 and axios running.
With the normal syntax my code looks something like:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'GetRequest',
  data () {
    return {
      infos: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/')
      .then(response => (this.infos = response.data))
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ infos }}
  </div>
</template>
```

This works just fine, but I use a template (https://github.com/justboil/admin-one-vue-tailwind) for my projekt which works with the new `<script setup>`.

I already found some solutions like:

```
<script setup>
 
import {onMounted} from "vue";
 
const {ref} = require("vue");
const axios = require("axios");
const info = ref([])
onMounted(async () => {
  await axios
      .get('https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/')
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data
 
      })
})
</script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ infos }}
  </div>
</template>
```

but it gives me *'this.infos' is assigned a value but never used*.
Does anyone know how I can assigne the value to the variabel and call it in the `<template>`?

### **Update:**

I found the solution by using `infos.value` instead of `this.infos`

````
<script setup>
import {onMounted} from "vue"
 
const {ref} = require("vue")
const axios = require("axios")
const infos = ref([])
onMounted(async () => {
  await axios
    .get('https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/')
    .then(response => {
      infos.value = response.data
    })
})
</script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ infos }}
  </div>
</template>
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `inject` for importing `axios` in each component. This way you can create some interceptors if they needed as well...

First you should install the axios plugin for `vue.js`.

`> npm install --save axios vue-axios`

When the installation finished just import the `axios` like below example:

##### main.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import axios from "./plugins/axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";

const app = createApp(App);

// Axios Plugin
app.use(VueAxios, axios);
app.provide("axios", app.config.globalProperties.axios);
```

##### inside any component

```js
import { inject } from "vue";

const axios = inject('axios');
// using axios as usual
```

Note: I used the `<script setup>` inside the component example.

PS: You can create an `axios` instance inside the `./plugins/axios.js` file if you need to use `interceptors` otherwise just import the `axios` as always inside `main.js` file!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I consider using the injection for this project.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your template you are accessing "infos" but the declared variable is "info"
2. In your onMounted callback your assignment should be without "this" just "info = response.data"

Any variable declared at the top level script would be accesible from the template.

More info here https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.htm and here
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html

Comment: Thank you as well for your help. The missing information was using .value

Comment: @Taraman You can click on the check mark on the left of the answer to say that it's the accepted answer